# Supabase - Allow file upload to authenticated users only

Tags: supabase

I want to allow all users to access the files on my bucket, but only authenticated users to upload, however when executing this code:

```
await supabase.auth.setSession({
    access_token: session.access_token,
    refresh_token: session.refresh_token
});
const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
    .from('card-pictures')
    .upload(`/${cardPicture.toString()}`, cardPicture);
```

I get the error:

```
  statusCode: '401',
  error: 'Invalid JWT',
  message: 'new row violates row-level security policy for table "objects"'
```

I can see that I am authenticated when logging the `session` object.

I have the following policy for the bucket:

[image: Policy allowing authenticated users access to the bucket with name 'card-pictures']

And under "other policies" I have the following policies on the "objects" table in my bucket:

[image: Template policy to allow authenticated users to upload]

What am I missing or doing wrong here? If I enable uploads for all users it works fine, so I know the problem is with the policies, but I can't tell what they're supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, but the `setSession` call is unnecessary.

I don't know where the `session` variable is coming from here, but you don't need this piece of code. The access token will be sent to the storage-api server automatically.

```js
await supabase.auth.setSession({
    access_token: session.access_token,
    refresh_token: session.refresh_token
});
```

Instead, verify that you are signed in with the following code. Also, I probably will sign in again, just to reset whatever you had with using the `setSession` call above.

```js
const { data } = await supabase.auth.getSession()
const { session } = data
console.log({session}) // verify that session exists and the user is signed in.

const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
    .from('card-pictures')
    .upload(`/${cardPicture.toString()}`, cardPicture);
```

Comment: session comes from the getSupabase method `const { session } = await getSupabase(event);`, using the getSession method and logging session I'm getting `{ session: null }`.

Comment: @Danyx Getting `null` for session means that you have no active session. Just make sure that you are signed in to Supabase before you make the request and you should be able to upload the image.

Comment: When I submit my form I can see on my app that I have an active session, and from what I read that session is kept on the event (hence `getSupabase(event)`), how else could I keep the session?

Comment: @Danyx Why do you think you have an active session when you submit the form when you are getting `null` when console logging the session? And where is this `getSupabase()` coming from? The Supabase client library has no such method.

Comment: on my layout I'm printing `$page.data.session.user.email`, and when submitting the form I can see my email; `getSupabase()` is coming from `@supabase/auth-helpers-sveltekit`, I didn't mention in my post I'm using sveltekit, but figured my issue was related to my policies, and no the framework. I now see that I can get a `supabaseClient` property from `getSupabase()`, but still don't know why my supabase object doesn't have a session, even though I am using it to log in.

Comment: @Danyx No matter what you see on the screen, if you are getting `null` as your session, then the session is `null`, and the upload operation is done as a non-signed in user. Are you trying to upload an image from the client or the server?